# Check if group in ExpandableListView has items

Tags: android

How can I check if a certain group in an ExpandableListView has items or not?

I want to do that verification after the user clicks the group to expand.
This is my code:

```
expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
        int count = parent.getChildCount();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return false;
    }
});
```

I've tried using `getChildCount()` but I always get this error:

```
03-10 15:36:23.175    4248-4248/pt.test_pro_gold E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xa
            at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:229)
            at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:265)
            at pt.test_pro_gold.ui.activities.Menu$2.onGroupClick(Menu.java:66)
```

Comment: This error is because you are passing the integer `count` to the `makeText` method. 

Android will try get an string resource with this integer as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#makeText(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get this number using the ExpandableListViewAdapter as follows:

```
int count = parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getChildrenCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a little mistake in the above code, the method `getChildrenCount` must receive the group position as a parameter as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html#getChildrenCount(int)).

You must implement the `ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener` interface and override the method `onGroupClick`.

Find below an example:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View view, int groupPosition, long id) {
        int noChild = 0;

        int childCount = parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getChildrenCount(groupPosition);
        if (childCount == noChild) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "There is no 'Child' for this 'Group'", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Hope it works for someone else.